# How to define the 'return type form' of a pinescript method/function?

Tags: methods, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a library method that I want to call in a const context. The problem is that I cannot define the type form of the output of the method and pine script uses the defaulted "series string" type.

My method looks like this:

```
// @function make_title - Make a unique title string by appending a number of "zero width space characters" on top of filling "special space characters" and also ident by prepending a number of "special space characters"
// @param this - The string that will be modified with the identation, filling and id characters
// @param ident - The number of "special space characters" to be prepended
// @param fill - The number of "special space characters" to be appended
// @param id - The number of "zero width space characters" to append to the string
// @returns string appended with the number of "zero width space characters"
export method make_title(simple string this, simple int ident = 0, simple int fill = 0, simple int id = 0) =>
    var string specialSpaceCharacter = ' '
    string identStr = ''
    for i = 0 to ident > 0 ? ident - 1 : na
        identStr := identStr + specialSpaceCharacter
    string fillStr = ''
    for i = 0 to fill > 0 ? fill - 1 : na
        fillStr := fillStr + specialSpaceCharacter
    var string zeroWidthSpaceCharacter = '​'
    string idStr = ''
    for i = 0 to id > 0 ? id - 1 : na
        idStr := idStr + zeroWidthSpaceCharacter
    identStr + this + fillStr + idStr
```

And I want to use it like this:

```
show = input.bool(defval = true, title = '​​My Title​'.make_title(ident = 2, fill = 1, id = 1))
```

but the error I get is:

> Cannot call 'input.bool' with argument 'title'='call 'make_title'
> (series string)'. An argument of 'series string' type was used but a
> 'const string' is expected.

Is it possible to overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

From the manual section "Libraries":

> Library functions always return a result that is either of “simple” or
> “series” form. You cannot use them to calculate values where “const”
> or “input” forms are required, as is the case with some Pine Script™
> built-in function arguments.

So, unfortunately, you cannot use result of a library function as `title` argument of `input()` function.

Comment: Thank you, Moebius, for your answer! Can I at least return a simple string from my function? Since all the input arguments are simple, I would expect the output to be simple as well.

Comment: I think so. As I understand, your function should return `simple` since all its arguments are of the `simple` form.